# Updating into a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm trying to add data from a file_handler i fetched from the site to the empty dictionary "self.currency_code", it wont update the dictionary

I have tried using the update function, i get no errors whatsoever but it still returns me an empty dictionary.

```
def fetch_data(self):
    self.currency_code = {}
    file = urlopen("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_DAILY/csv")
    file_handler = []
    for row in file:
        file_handler.append(row.decode())

    print(file_handler)
    print(len(file_handler))

    for row in file_handler:
        if row.startswith("FX"):
            line = row.split(",")
            currency = line[2].split(" to")[0]
            currency = currency[1:]
            self.currency_code[currency.title()] = line[0]
        else:
            continue
    print(self.currency_code)
```

Comment: Have you checked if `file_handler` has data in it? Or maybe, no lines start with "FX"?

Comment: the way you parse the file is complete wrong. look at the file structure. Also note that no line whatsoever starts with `FX`. non-empty lines start with `"` because all values are in quotes

Comment: @luis.parravicini yes the file_handler has data on it fetched from the .csv file, and there is a row which has id that start with "FX"

Comment: @buran am fetching the id whom all the id's start with "FX" in the .csv file

Comment: open the file in notepad and you will see that all values are in quotes thus each line starts with double quote

Comment: @buran yeah you're right, thanks alot    

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to extract currency code into a dictionary, I'm not sure about waht you want, but it may help you as a starting point.

```py
from urllib.request import urlopen
from collections import defaultdict


currency_code = {}
file = urlopen("https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_DAILY/csv")
file_handler = []
for row in file:
    file_handler.append(row.decode())

currency = file_handler[10:36]
clean_currency = []
for row in currency:
    tmp = row.split(",")
    tmp = [t.strip() for t in tmp]
    tmp = [t.replace('"', "") for t in tmp]
    clean_currency.append(tmp)

currency_code = {}
for Id, label, description in clean_currency[1:]:
    currency_code[Id] = label
```

Output

```py
{   'FXAUDCAD': 'AUD/CAD',
    'FXBRLCAD': 'BRL/CAD',
    'FXCHFCAD': 'CHF/CAD',
    'FXCNYCAD': 'CNY/CAD',
    'FXEURCAD': 'EUR/CAD',
    'FXGBPCAD': 'GBP/CAD',
    'FXHKDCAD': 'HKD/CAD',
    'FXIDRCAD': 'IDR/CAD',
    'FXINRCAD': 'INR/CAD',
    'FXJPYCAD': 'JPY/CAD',
    'FXKRWCAD': 'KRW/CAD',
    'FXMXNCAD': 'MXN/CAD',
    'FXMYRCAD': 'MYR/CAD',
    'FXNOKCAD': 'NOK/CAD',
    'FXNZDCAD': 'NZD/CAD',
    'FXPENCAD': 'PEN/CAD',
    'FXRUBCAD': 'RUB/CAD',
    'FXSARCAD': 'SAR/CAD',
    'FXSEKCAD': 'SEK/CAD',
    'FXSGDCAD': 'SGD/CAD',
    'FXTHBCAD': 'THB/CAD',
    'FXTRYCAD': 'TRY/CAD',
    'FXTWDCAD': 'TWD/CAD',
    'FXUSDCAD': 'USD/CAD',
    'FXZARCAD': 'ZAR/CAD'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I still think you approach to parse the csv file is at least not optimal, but if you managed to get desired results - fine. I would like to show you better approach to get/parse the same data - using json

```
import requests
url = 'https://www.bankofcanada.ca/valet/observations/group/FX_RATES_DAILY/json'
resp = requests.get(url)
data = resp.json()
for key, value in data['seriesDetail'].items():
    print(f'key ==> {key}')
    for key2, value2 in value.items():
        print(f'\tkey2 ==> {key2}')
        print(f'\tvalue2 ==> {value2}')
```

output

```
key ==> FXAUDCAD
        key2 ==> label
        value2 ==> AUD/CAD
        key2 ==> description
        value2 ==> Australian dollar to Canadian dollar daily exchange rate
        key2 ==> dimension
        value2 ==> {'key': 'd', 'name': 'date'}
key ==> FXBRLCAD
        key2 ==> label
        value2 ==> BRL/CAD
        key2 ==> description
        value2 ==> Brazilian real to Canadian dollar daily exchange rate
        key2 ==> dimension
        value2 ==> {'key': 'd', 'name': 'date'}

... many rows intentionally removed

key ==> FXVNDCAD
        key2 ==> label
        value2 ==> VND/CAD
        key2 ==> description
        value2 ==> Vietnamese dong to Canadian dollar daily exchange rate
        key2 ==> dimension
        value2 ==> {'key': 'd', 'name': 'date'}
```

you can explore the json response to get better understanding of its structure